Angular 8 - Display array data in table
I have JSON in the below format.
[
  {
    "group": "A",
    "teams": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "France"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Portugual"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "group": "B",
    "teams": [
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "China"
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "US"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "group": "C",
    "teams": [
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Italy"
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "AUS"
      }
    ]
  }
]

I want to display the above JSON as the table below:


What Have you tried so far? Can you post some tried snippets??

Always try to provide as much info as possible. Otherwise, there is starting point for us to help.

I have tried with dynamic head but not for data.



Name

{{ yr }}





{{ dataobj.name }}
{{ dataobj.id }}



Transpose data will make it easier to display data as desired.
Each object after transposition will be in this structure/format:
{ name: string; [key: string]: any }

You can work with Array.reduce() to transform the data with concept:

Get all the group values as props for generating as property in the object and loop as the table column.

Iterate each teams array to create an object and assign the property value based on the group value.


props!: string[];

output!: any[];

ngOnInit() {
  this.props = this.input.map((x: any) => x.group);

  this.output = this.input.reduce(
    (acc: { name: string; [key: string]: any }[], cur: any) => {
      for (let team of cur.teams) {
        let obj: { name: string; [key: string]: any } = { name: team.name };

        for (let prop of this.props) {
          obj[prop] = prop === cur.group ? team.id : undefined;
        }

       acc.push(obj);
      }

      return acc;
    },
    [] as { name: string; [key: string]: any }[]
  );
}


You should need a loop to render the columns and get the value by property name.

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <ng-container *ngFor="let prop of props">
        <th>{{prop}}</th>
      </ng-container>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let row of output">
      <td>{{row.name}}</td>
      <ng-container *ngFor="let prop of props">
        <th>{{row[prop] ?? 'NA'}}</th>
      </ng-container>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

The benefit of this approach is making it dynamic to handle the expandable group (such as: D, E, F and so on).
Demo @ StackBlitz
